# How to get combobox-value from 'SelectedItem' in DataGrid

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I'm having trouble reading the selecteditem value of a combobox element which is part of a datagrid element. I suspect thre is a problem with the binding.
With "$WPFDataGrid.SelectedItems.combobox" I get all values but not the selecteditem value of the combobox.

```
    <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Combobox" Visibility="Visible" Width="300">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                           <ComboBox
                           ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Combobox}"
                           SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Result, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

```
class myRow{
[Array]$Combobox
[string]$Hostname
}

$test1 = New-Object myRow -Property @{Hostname = "test1"; Combobox = "TEST1","TEST2" }

$WPFDataGrid.ItemsSource = @($test1)
```

Full Code:[Full Code @GitHub](https://github.com/jkuehnis/PowerShell-DataGrid-with-Combobox/blob/master/DataGrid.ps1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution:
In the XAML area the binding path had to be changed from ' SelectedItem="{Binding Path=**Result**' to ' SelectedItem="{Binding Path=**Combobox**'.

```
   SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Combobox, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```